# How to set the counter for examples to continue from theorems?

Tags: formatting, counters

I have the following lines:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{thesis}

\usepackage{verbatim} 
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsfonts,amscd,amsrefs}
\newtheoremstyle{component}{}{}{}{}{\itshape}{.}{.5em}{\thmnote{#3}#1}
    \theoremstyle{component}
    \newtheorem*{component}{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{New Chapter}

\begin{definition}
This is a definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{example}
This is an example.
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

1. What exactly does \theoremstyle{component}{} do?
2. How do I make it so that example's counter follow from theorems/definitions/lemma and only refresh at new section?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: if you have \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[...] replace it by \newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

Comment: @touhami those I quoted above are the only \newtheorem{} lines I can find in the preamble (?) of the document. If I add in your comment will it cause any major problems for me?

Comment: Could you post any `\newtheorem{}` lines that might be inside `thesis.cls`?

Comment: Btw, the `\newtheoremstyle{component}` is defining a new style for theorem-like environments (one in which the header is in italics, followed by a point, and is not numbered, among other characteristics); `\theoremstyle{component}` ensures that any new theorem defined below follows that style. So if you write below it `\newtheorem{ntheo}{My thing}`, then you can use in your document `\begin{ntheo} Blah blah \end{ntheo}` and it will display "My thing. Blah blah" (with "My thing" in italics following the "component" style)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add to your preamble

```
\let\theexample\thetheorem
\let\oldexample\example\let\eoldexample\endexample
\renewenvironment{example}{%
\refstepcounter{theorem}\oldexample}{\eoldexample}
```

Comment: Note that this solution will fail if "theorem" is following another counter, namely if it is defined through e.g. `\newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{Theorem}`. Thus it might be necessary to replace the two instances of "theorem" in the above solution by "definition" or "lemma" or whichever is the main counter.